# Best mac configuration For iOS development i

Tags: ios, mac, xcode

I need suggestion for best configuration in affordable price for basically iOS development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to me mac book pro will be a kind of best and affordable option for you with your custom configurations.
Now its up to you that how you configure your system.

Use following link to check price [Configure link](http://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/macbook-pro?product=MF839LL/A&step=config)